# Symfony Quiz Entity Design

Tags: mysql, database-design

Dear Helpful SE Users,

In my quest to get more experience of Symfony I thought I'd write a quiz website which I can use at school (I know that moodle does this but it is a bit overkill for my purposes). The idea is to have quizzes that pupils can do as many times as they like. I know similar questions have been asked before and my initial idea is based on this research.

Initially I'm only interested in using it for me so it only needs a limited number of courses (the year groups that I teach) and withing each course I can have a number of categories for quizzes corresponding to the different subjects within the course.

I have no experience of designing databases consisting of many tables so please go easy on my initial idea as it may contain redundancies.

I have tried to leave it general so I can include different question types (numerical/multichoice/true-false).

[image: Initial ERD]

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Sorry, I am just checking whether this will work or is the best approach.  Is the response table the best way of getting the users answers?

Comment: Can't critique a schema without seeing the `SELECTs`.

Comment: Okay, I will have to go away and think some more then

Comment: Try to formulate a few queries that your use cases require, and you will immediately see if the model is appropriate. As for "the best approach", what's your criteria for "best"?

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  Sorry for being too vague.